# echo data from mySQL database into 3x3 grid

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

so i am trying to echo some data from my database.

```
    <?php

        $connect = mysql_connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
        mysql_select_db("xxxxx", $connect) or die(mysql_error());

        $lsql = "SELECT * FROM xxxxxxx ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 6";

        $lquery = mysql_query($lsql) or die(mysql_error());


        while ($lrow = mysql_fetch_array($lquery))
            $lrows[] = $lrow;

                foreach ($lrows as $lrow){
                      $ProperBrand = $lrow['ProperBrand'];
                      $LowerBrand = $lrow['LowerBrand'];
                      $PageTitle = $lrow['PageTitle'];
                      $PageH1 = $lrow['PageH1'];
                      $PageExcerpt = $lrow['PageExcerpt'];
                      $ContentP1 = $lrow['ContentP1'];
                      $ContentP2 = $lrow['ContentP2'];
                      $Image1 = $lrow['Image1'];
                      $Image2 = $lrow['Image2'];
                      $Image3 = $lrow['Image3'];
                      $BrandURL = $lrow['BrandURL'];

                    echo ('
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="'. $Image1 .'" class="top-images-larger">
                    </div>
                                ');



                    } 
    ?>
```

I can echo it like the above and that will work correctly but i can't seem to figure out how I will be able to do this with a structured bootstrap row. I want to have a 9 grid of 3x3 on mobile and have done it like the below:

```
<div class="row visible-xs" align="center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 padding-bottom">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 padding-bottom">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 padding-bottom">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
        <img src="/images/brandlogos/logo.png" class="top-images">
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs col-sm-4 spacer-t">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">View All Stores</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i was to echo like i have done in the above example it will break the structure of this "grid".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any special reason why you're using a deprecated mysql api and not mysqli or pdo with a prepared statement, should user input ever be part of the picture?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use the echo to display a grid with html table:

```
<?php
    echo "<table>
          <tr>
            <th>column1</th>
            <th>column2</th> 
            <th>column3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>".$lrow['yourdata']."</td>
            <td>".$lrow['yourdata2']."</td> 
            <td>".$lrow['yourdata3']."</td>
          </tr>
        </table>";
?>
```

Hope i have helped!

Comment: Hey, but if there are 9 blocks it will echo 3 tables using the example you have given above no?